# Creating a Dynamic SumProduct Function with Two Arrays

Tags: excel, offset, sumproduct

I am trying to combine the offset function in excel with sumproduct because I want to take two arrays and multiple them based on the starting point and length specified.  For example:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16

If I started at 4 and 8 and selected to go 3 columns back and then multiplied and summed the row arrays from the specified range: ie 1,2 to 4,8.
1*2
2*4
3*6
4*8
Desired result would be (2+8+18+32) = 60

Offset, sumproduct combinations without success.  I've seen index with counta and it doesn't appear to be the solution

See above

Cannot get the table working.  Any help is greatly appreciated so that this process can be dynamic in the event the specified range were 2 rather than 3 etc.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First row starts in A2. Second row starts in B2.

Starting column in C6 (really it's the ending column). Number of columns to include in C7.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(A2,0,C6-C7,1,C7)*OFFSET(A2,1,C6-C7,1,C7))
```

The first offset says

- Start in A2
- Move zero rows
- Move zero columns. In C6 there is a 4 (the last column to include) and in C7 there is a four (the total number of columns to include). Change C7 to a "2" to only sum 3*6 and 4*8.
- Resize to 1 row
- Resize to 4 columns

[image: sumproduct formula]

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating this solution for the sheet I'm using. I want to do sumproduct offsetting x columns forward to the selected end cell.  For some reason I can't screenshot the table to show you in this our comments.

Comment: I added a picture for clarity. The "4" is right most column (4 and 8) and the "3" is how many columns to include (B, C, and D).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of alternatives using Sumproduct and Column:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:H2*A3:H3*(COLUMN(A2:H2)>=C6-C7)*(COLUMN(A2:H2)<=C6))
```

or using Index:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(A2:H2,C6-C7):INDEX(A2:H2,C6),INDEX(A3:H3,C6-C7):INDEX(A3:H3,C6))
```

What if the inputs were *arrays* rather than ranges like this?

```
column(A:H)

column(A:H)*2
```

None of the previous methods would work but you could do something like this

```
=SUM(INDEX(COLUMN(A:H),N(IF({1},ROW(INDEX(A:A,C6-C7):INDEX(A:A,C6)))))
*INDEX(COLUMN(A:H)*2,N(IF({1},ROW(INDEX(A:A,C6-C7):INDEX(A:A,C6))))))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>